# Android Internal Storage advice

Tags: android, storage

I am developing an app for University.

I have bought a Nexus 7 google tablet for the task (I wanted a tablet anyway :P)

I need to convert data I record on the app onto a text file that can be moved onto a PC.. Now, from what I can tell android has high security on 'Internal Storage' which is the only type of storage the Nexus 7 has, and I cant seem to be able to write a text file to a folder or anything.. and I can't even find the app's data folder on the windows explorer so I presume its hidden..

It appears its possible with 'External Storage' such as an SD card but the Nexus 7 does not have an SD card slot..

what should I do? Is it possible to be done on the Nexus 7?

Comment: you can still write to external storage http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: But the Nexus 7 tablet doesn't have external storage? When I plug it into my PC it only has Internal Storage.. I thought External Storage speaks about SD Cards which you can put into your Tablet, but the Nexus 7 Doesnt support sd cards.

Comment: If you read my link you will then see that there is always external storage

Answer (score 2):

All Android devices have "external storage" regardless whether or not they have SD card support (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). The naming is unfortunately misleading.

If you save your data to app's default external storage, you can access them on a PC in */Android/Data/[your app's package name]/files*

Comment: Okay, I understand! So if I write a text file to the default path is will go in there? and I can drag stuff from there onto my PC without a problem?

Comment: Yes, if you write to `new File(Environment.getExternalFilesDir(), "test.txt")` then you can find it as _/Android/Data/[your app's package name]/files/test.txt_